# duplicate vector into matrix r

Tags: r, vector, matrix

Wondering how to duplicate a vector into a matrix in R. For example

```
v = 1:10
dup = duplicate(V,2)
```

where `dup` looks like `rbind(1:10,1:10)`. Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up:  `duplicated` is a function which finds duplicates *within* a vector.  And as @thelatemail alludes to, `R` recycles, and so you simply need to indicate how many rows your matrix requires and `R` will automatically repeat the vector for you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you're looking for `replicate`.

```
t(replicate(2, v))
```

Comment: worth noting to readers that `replicate` is typically not used like this; also, it's much slower than thelatemail's approach below. Anyway +1 for readability/elegance.

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively:

```
matrix(v, nrow=2, ncol=length(v), byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: which is faster than transposing the result without using `byrow` (as I guess expected)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I just multiply it by a ones vector ..

for instance, if v is a column vector :
v [1 1] -> [v v]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Moud's answer but with some more clarity.

```
n <- 10
v <- c(1,4,3,6,4,7,8,1) # random
t(t(rep(1, n))) %*% v
```

Should be fast but not as elegant as some of the other answers.